# ssh sed not changing variables correctly

Tags: bash, ssh, sed

I'm trying to use sed to change a variable in the site.js file on my server.

Here is the line: `var url = "page.php";` I'm looking to just substitute page.php for whatever.php.

I thought this would be pretty simple and I figured this would work with no issues:

```
sed -i "s/\url = \".*\"/\url = \"page2.php\"/" /home/site.js
```

It works okay except instead of getting: `var url = "page2.php";` I get: `var R1 = "page2.php";`

Why is the url value being changed to R1 when I use sed here?

Comment: Why do you prefix `url` with backslash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `\` before `url`.

```
sed -i -r 's#url\s*=\s*"[^"]+"#url = "page2.php"#' /home/site.js
```

Extra escaping of `"` can be eliminated by enclosing sed expression with `'` instead of `"`

It's better to use different separator than `/` (here `#`) when the strings themselves may contain `/`

Comment: Thanks it was the \ before the url, I had made a mistake there.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
sed -i -r 's@(var\s+url\s*=\s*")[^"]+"@\1whatever.php"@' file.js
```

`/` is not mandatory as delimiter, I've picked up `@` there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example: Took me while to figure that you change the `/` for delimiter and not the  `/`  in the directory path.

Use `@` instead of `/` for sed delimiter if you have dir path names.

First I tried this:

```
[root@ip-172-35-24-37 ec2-user]# egrep -q "^(\s*\S+\s+)/dev/shm(\s+\S+\s+\S+)(\s+\S+\s+\S+)(\s*#.*)?\s*$" /etc/fstab && sed -ri "s/^(\s*\S+\s+)/dev/shm(\s+\S+\s+\S+)(\s+\S+\s+\S+)(\s*#.*)?\s*$/\1/dev/shm\2nodev\3\4/" /etc/fstab
```

And got this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'
```

So then I used `@` for the sed delimiter instead of `/`:

```
[root@ip-172-35-24-37 ec2-user]# egrep -q "^(\s*\S+\s+)/dev/shm(\s+\S+\s+\S+)(\s+\S+\s+\S+)(\s*#.*)?\s*$" /etc/fstab && sed -ri "s@^(\s*\S+\s+)/dev/shm(\s+\S+\s+\S+)(\s+\S+\s+\S+)(\s*#.*)?\s*$@\1/dev/shm\2nodev\3\4@@" /etc/fstab
[root@ip-172-35-24-37 ec2-user]#
```

And it worked.

You can  use something else besides `@` for a delimiter like  `!` or `?` or `%`. Just don't use `/`  if you have dir paths.